# UcanAccess error reading .MDB db from samba connection

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I'm using UcanAccess (http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to read a .MDB database from Java.
The application is running in a Ubuntu server and it is reading the database from a Samba connection.

On Windows machine it works, but on Linux I've some problems.

Here some data:

```
Url: jdbc:ucanaccess:///mnt/database/TEST.MDB;jackcessOpener=it.plugins.CryptCodecOpener
```

The database requires a password when I open it from Access. The database is used from another application, in fact I see in the same folder the `.ldb` file.

When I try to read data from DB I've this exception:

```
Dataset App.ti 1gg mdb (17) Plugin: TestMdb.jar: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.5 invalid authorization specification - not found: Admin
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at it.test.plugins.Testmdb.TestMdb.getConnection(TestMdb.java:120)
    at it.test.plugins.Testmdb.TestMdb.testConnessione(TestMdb.java:135)
    at it.test.plugins.PluginManager.getAppuntamenti(PluginManager.java:247)
    at it.test.plugins.PluginManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$180b607d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at it.test.plugins.PluginManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ece2d5aa.getAppuntamenti(<generated>)
    at it.test.task.AppuntamentiTask.esegui(AppuntamentiTask.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor141.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.5 invalid authorization specification - not found: Admin
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.<init>(UcanaccessConnection.java:110)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:254)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: invalid authorization specification - not found: Admin
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.getHSQLDBConnection(DBReference.java:440)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.<init>(UcanaccessConnection.java:107)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid authorization specification - not found: Admin
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.rights.UserManager.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.rights.UserManager.getUser(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
```

But if I do a `cp originalDatabase.MDB copiedDatabase.MDB` and I change UcanAccess url using the copied database, everything works fine without any change!

This is how I mounted the share:

```
//192.168.101.100/g/DATABASE /mnt/database cifs user=,password=,gid=1005,uid=1001  0 0
```

where `1001` is the uid of the user that runs my java application.

I want to point out that the same application on Windows works fine without the need to copy the original database in order to access to it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try with the latest version of UCanAccess (currently 4.0.4)?

Comment: @GordThompson I made a very quick test and it seems to work, but I'll ping you later to give the final response. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? I've experienced a similar issue with OS X, which I also got around by copying the DB.